# Twig checkbox is checked

Tags: symfony-forms

please how can I do something as follows with twig checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
{% if checkbox is checked %}
#do_it 
{% else %} 
#do_that 
{% endif %}
```

help me, please

Answer (score 1):

The controller:

```
$dispo = $mezzo->getAuDisponibile ();
// table column AuDisponibile is boolean
...
...
return $this-render ('anagrafiche/automezzi.html.twig', ['dispo' => $dispo]);
```

The template:

```
{% if dispo  %}
<input input type='checkbox' name="idisponibile" value="SI" checked>
{% else %}
<input input type='checkbox' name="idisponibile" value="SI">
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a form field is checked with in example,

```
{% if form.field.children.KEY.vars.checked %}
   Do something here
{% endif %}
```

Using it inside a loop.

```
{% for child in form.field %}
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" {{ child.vars.checked == true ? "Checked" }}>
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" {{ form.field.children.KEY.vars.checked ? "Checked" }}>
```

**KEY** being the array key.

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes return string value.

```
{% if node.field_mycheckbox.value == '1' %}
  <p>print 1</p>
{% else %}
  <p>print 0</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What is node and field_mycheckbox referring to?

Comment: It's the name of your fields, maybe `form.newletters` or whatever name the field has :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
{% if checkbox.checked %}
```

instead of this:

```
{% if checkbox is checked %}
```